# Optimize add row in xls file with xlwt

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I have a big problem with a large xls file. When my app add a new stats record (a new row at the end of the file) there is a very long time (one minute). If I replace it with an empty xls file this work the best (1-2 seconds). So I'm trying to optimize this if possible.

I use something like:

```
def add_stats_record():
    # Add record
    lock = LockFile(STATS_FILE)
    with lock:
        # Open for read
        rb = open_workbook(STATS_FILE, formatting_info=True)
        sheet_records = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

        # record_id
        START_ROW = sheet_records.nrows
        try:
            record_id = int(sheet_records.cell(START_ROW - 1, 0).value) + 1
        except:
            record_id = 1

        # Open for write
        wb = copy(rb)
        sheet_records = wb.get_sheet(0)

        # Set normal style
        style_normal = xlwt.XFStyle()
        normal_font = xlwt.Font()
        style_normal.font = normal_font

        # Prepare some data here
        ........................
        # then:

        for i, col in enumerate(SHEET_RECORDS_COLS):
            sheet_records.write(START_ROW, i, possible_values.get(col[0], ''),
                                style_normal)

        wb.save(STATS_FILE)
```

Do you see here something to improve? Or can you give me a better idea / example how to do this?

Comment: Thanks, Ionică. A solution here is important for me, because if I have no solution I must re-implement the functionality using csv file or something else.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? What is the approximate size of the excel sheet? What kind of data?

Comment: 30000-40000 rows. Simple text: string and numbers.

Comment: I think the problem is not the kind of data added, because if I use a new file it's very fast. I think somehow the entire file is copied in memory before adding the new row and this process takes a lot of time when the file is big.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure that I am working on comparable data.

Comment: Maybe also good to know: each row I fill has 30 columns of data. The file has now aprox. 20 MB.

Comment: if you are using xlwt/xlrd it doesn't look promising, I measured the time required for each step and the `copy` operation takes about 60% of the total time. Nothing much to optimize in one line.

Comment: just tried another approach, putting the most time demanding operation (`copy`) in another process and execute the rest independently. Unfortunately it makes things actually much worse since a lot data has to be copied between the two processes.

Comment: You gotta show some work for your bounty: Finally found a solution which is moderately faster than the original code. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. :) You have done a great work. But I think I will reimplement my work, maybe using SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the answer you want to hear but there is hardly anything to optimize.

```
import xlwt, xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy as copy
from time import time

def add_stats_record():
    #Open for read
    start_time = time()
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook(STATS_FILE, formatting_info=True)
    sheet_records_original = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    print('Elapsed time for opening:            %.2f' % (time()-start_time))
    #Record_id
    start_time = time()
    START_ROW = sheet_records_original.nrows
    SHEET_RECORDS_COLS = sheet_records_original.ncols
    try:
        record_id = int(sheet_records.cell(START_ROW - 1, 0).value) + 1
    except:
        record_id = 1
    print('Elapsed time for record ID:          %.2f' % (time()-start_time))
    #Open for write
    start_time = time()
    wb = copy(rb)
    sheet_records = wb.get_sheet(0)
    print('Elapsed time for write:              %.2f' % (time()-start_time))
    #Set normal style
    style_normal = xlwt.XFStyle()
    normal_font = xlwt.Font()
    style_normal.font = normal_font

    #Read all the data and get some stats
    start_time = time()
    max_col = {}
    start_time = time()
    for col_idx in range(0,16):
        max_value = 0
        for row_idx in range(START_ROW):
            if sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value:
                val = float(sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value)
                if val > max_value:
                    max_col[col_idx] = str(row_idx) + ';' + str(col_idx)

    text_cells = [[0 for x in range(15)] for y in range(START_ROW)] 
    for col_idx in range(16,31):
        max_value = 0
        for row_idx in range(START_ROW):
            if sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value:
                val = str(sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value).replace('text', '').count(str(col_idx))
                if val > max_value:
                    max_col[col_idx] = str(row_idx) + ';' + str(col_idx)
    print('Elapsed time for reading data/stats: %.2f' % (time()-start_time))
    #Write the stats row
    start_time = time()
    for i in range(SHEET_RECORDS_COLS):
        sheet_records.write(START_ROW, i, max_col[i], style_normal)

    start_time = time()
    wb.save(STATS_FILE)
    print('Elapsed time for writing:            %.2f' % (time()-start_time))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    STATS_FILE = 'output.xls'
    start_time2 = time()
    add_stats_record()
    print ('Total time:                         %.2f' % (time() - start_time2))
```

> Elapsed time for opening:            2.43
>   Elapsed time for record ID:  0.00
>   Elapsed time for write:              7.62
>   Elapsed time for reading data/stats: 2.35
>   Elapsed time for writing:            3.33
>   Total time:                         15.75

From those results it becomes pretty clear that there is hardly any room for improvement in your code. Open/copy/write make up the bulk time but are just simple calls to `xlrd/xlwt`.

Using `on_demand=True` in [`open_workbook`](http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/copy.html) doesn't help either.

Using `openpyxl` doesn't improve performance as well.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from time import time

#Load workbook
start_time = time()
wb = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
print('Elapsed time for loading workbook: %.2f' % (time.time()-start_time))    

#Read all data
start_time = time()
ws = wb.active
cell_range1 = ws['A1':'P20001']
cell_range2 = ws['Q1':'AF20001']
print('Elapsed time for reading workbook: %.2f' % (time.time()-start_time))    

#Save to a new workbook
start_time = time()
wb.save("output_tmp.xlsx")
print('Elapsed time for saving workbook:  %.2f' % (time.time()-start_time))
```

> Elapsed time for loading workbook: 22.35
>   Elapsed time for reading workbook:  0.00
>   Elapsed time for saving workbook:  21.11

Ubuntu 14.04 (Virtual machine)/Python2.7-64bit/Regular hard disk (with native Windows 10 similar results, Python 3 performs worse in loading but better in writing).

---

Random data was generated using Pandas and Numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#just random numbers
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000,30), columns=range(0,30))
#convert half the columns to text
for i in range(15,30):
    df[i].apply(str)
    df[i] = 'text' + df[i].astype(str)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(STATS_FILE)
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

---

After some fiddling with `multiprocessing` I found a slightly improved solution. Since the `copy` operation was the most time consuming operation and having a shared `workbook` made performance worse, a different approach was taken. Both threads read the original workbook, one reads the data, calculates the statistics and writes them to a file (`tmp.txt`), the other one copies the workbook, waits for the statistics file to appear and then writes it to the newly copied workbook.

Difference: 12% less time needed in total (n=3 for both scripts). Not great but I cannot think of another way of doing, except for not using Excel files.

**xls_copy.py**

```
def xls_copy(STATS_FILE, START_ROW, style_normal):
    from xlutils.copy import copy as copy
    from time import sleep, time
    from os import stat
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    print('started 2nd thread')
    start_time = time()
    rb = open_workbook(STATS_FILE, formatting_info=True)
    wb = copy(rb)
    sheet_records = wb.get_sheet(0)
    print('2: Elapsed time for xls_copy:         %.2f' % (time()-start_time))

    counter = 0
    filesize = stat('tmp.txt').st_size

    while filesize == 0 and counter < 10**5:
        sleep(0.01)
        filesize = stat('tmp.txt').st_size
        counter +=1
    with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            cells = line.split(';')
            sheet_records.write(START_ROW, int(cells[0]), cells[1], style_normal)

    start_time = time()
    wb.save('tmp_' + STATS_FILE)
    print('2: Elapsed time for writing:          %.2f' % (time()-start_time))
```

**xlsx_multi.py**

```
from xls_copy import xls_copy
import xlwt, xlrd
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def add_stats_record():

    #Open for read
    start_time = time()
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook(STATS_FILE, formatting_info=True)
    sheet_records_original = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    print('Elapsed time for opening:            %.2f' % (time()-start_time))
    #Record_id
    start_time = time()
    START_ROW = sheet_records_original.nrows
    f = open('tmp.txt', 'w')
    f.close()
    #Set normal style
    style_normal = xlwt.XFStyle()
    normal_font = xlwt.Font()
    style_normal.font = normal_font

    #start 2nd thread
    p = Process(target=xls_copy, args=(STATS_FILE, START_ROW, style_normal,))
    p.start()
    print('continuing with 1st thread')
    SHEET_RECORDS_COLS = sheet_records_original.ncols
    try:
        record_id = int(sheet_records.cell(START_ROW - 1, 0).value) + 1
    except:
        record_id = 1
    print('Elapsed time for record ID:          %.2f' % (time()-start_time))

    #Read all the data and get some stats
    start_time = time()
    max_col = {}
    start_time = time()
    for col_idx in range(0,16):
        max_value = 0
        for row_idx in range(START_ROW):
            if sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value:
                val = float(sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value)
                if val > max_value:
                    max_col[col_idx] = str(row_idx) + ';' + str(col_idx)

    text_cells = [[0 for x in range(15)] for y in range(START_ROW)] 
    for col_idx in range(16,31):
        max_value = 0
        for row_idx in range(START_ROW):
            if sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value:
                val = str(sheet_records_original.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value).replace('text', '').count(str(col_idx))
                if val > max_value:
                    max_col[col_idx] = str(row_idx) + ';' + str(col_idx)
    #write statistics to a temp file
    with open('tmp.txt', 'w') as f:
        for k in max_col:
            f.write(str(k) + ';' + max_col[k] + str('\n'))
    print('Elapsed time for reading data/stats: %.2f' % (time()-start_time))
    p.join()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    done = False
    wb = None
    STATS_FILE = 'output.xls'
    start_time2 = time()
    add_stats_record()
    print ('Total time:                          %.2f' % (time() - start_time2))
```